# Searching and Saving values from a text file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, full-text-search, text-files

I am creating an app through android studio that can display a student's student ID. 
The student will have to log in inside the app, but after that, I need to be able to store the student's information for later use.

To start, I need to check if they are listed in the student body.

I have all of the student's names in a text file along with their student ID numbers, but how would I search this file from Android Studio, and how would I save the values of that student for use in the app?

Comment: have a look on how to store data in android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create SQLite db first .Than convert The text-to SQL INSERT Commands  or CSV to SQL Converter . run those Script in SQLite Bowser .So that student name and id would be inserted in db . you can this tool  [Excel-to SQL INSERT Commands Text Wizard](http://tools.perceptus.ca/text-wiz.php?ops=7). it can be useful.